# Change String in dropdown

Tags: java, javafx

First I get the relevent ID (called dropid):

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

Then I try to modify the ID by removing and adding the new String:

```
comboBox.getItems().remove(dropid);
comboBox.getItems().add(dropid, "newstring");
```

But now the list sometimes gets mixed, so the string gets moved one position up. What would be the proper way of doing this without the list changing order?

Comment: have you tried using `getItems().set(dropid, "newstring");`?

Comment: According to doc `set(int index, E element)
Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element (optional operation).` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#set-int-E-).

Comment: Get rid of `remove` and use `set(id, string)` and it should work.

Comment: @Sedrick Was not aware of 'set'. That worked, thanks.